# How to create an upstart process in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I am trying to create a process to be automatically started and maintained by Ubuntu's upstart (Ubuntu 12.04). I have been looking at [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto) as well as on [this page](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html) and I am aware of the [upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) and [upstart stanzas](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas#pre-start). Using especially the information from the first two likes, I did the following to incorporate such a process. First, I created a file `/etc/init/testservice.conf` with the following content:

```
# myservice - myservice job file

description "my service description"
author "Me <myself@i.com>"

# Stanzas
#
# Stanzas control when and how a process is started and stopped
# See a list of stanzas here: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas#respawn

# When to start the service
start on runlevel [2345]

# When to stop the service
stop on runlevel [016]

# Automatically restart process if crashed
respawn

# Essentially lets upstart know the process will detach itself to the background
#expect fork

chdir /home/user/testcode

# Start the process
exec python mycommand.py
```

with some simple dummy python code `mycommand.py` residing in the directory `/home/user/testcode`. Checking with `initctl list` or `ps` I see that the command is not yet running. Therefore, I tried to start it 'manually' according to [this page](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html) with

```
start testservice
```

which produced the following output

```
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.88" (uid=1000 pid=9103 comm="start testservice ) interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" estination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

but did not start the process `mycommand.py`.

What am I doing wrong? How to tell `ubuntu` and/or `upstart` to run the command?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate. I cannot find the answer on how to start the process on the fly. Do I, for example, need to reboot the entire system to start the processes? If so, this is the solution. But I prefer a command line solution.

Comment: Run your command with `sudo`. `sudo start testservice`.

Comment: Oh great. I expected it to be something really stupid and trivial. And the error message did not really help, if it is related anyway. Thanks a lot